# Compose Drag Drop (passing data between components) - draggable item state doesn't change when scrolling bottom-top

Tags: android, kotlin, drag-and-drop, android-jetpack-compose

I'm working on an implementation of drag and drop with Jetpack Compose. Its already capable of drag-dropping data from one place to another and auto scrolling when draggable item meets top-bottom edges.

Now I'm trying to add changing of draggable item state when dragging over - general content (Initiated), enabled drop targets (Enabled) and disabled drop targets (Disabled). It works quite well when dragging down, but when dragging up it stays in default - Initiated state. And I need help figuring this out and fixing asap.

How it looks:

[image]

Full code in `draggable-item` branch -> [github repo](https://github.com/zarin-raim/DragDrop/blob/draggable-item/dragdrop/src/main/java/com/zarinraim/dragdrop/DropTarget.kt)

I can pinpoint problem source, but it can't find why it happens - whether I'm using it wrong or `onGloballyPositioned/boundsInRoot/contains` API has a bug.

```
var isItemInDropTarget by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
var wasInTarget by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }

Box(
    modifier = modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            it.boundsInRoot().let { rect ->
                isItemInDropTarget = (rect.contains(dragPosition) && state.isDragging)
                    .also { inDropTarget ->
                        if (inDropTarget != wasInTarget) {
                            Log.d(Tag, "isItemInDropTarget changed: $wasInTarget >>> $inDropTarget")
                            wasInTarget = inDropTarget
                        }
                    }
            }
        },
)
```

`Rect.contains()` is somehow triggered two times, and later defines draggable item state (in `LaunchedEffect`, but it doesn't matter here).

```
//Drag started - true - as drag source is also a drop target and item is in bounds
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: false >>> true

// Hover over next target down 
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: true >>> false
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: false >>> true
// Hover over next target down
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: true >>> false
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: false >>> true

// Hover over next target up - notice reverse order
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: false >>> true
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: true >>> false
// Hover over next target up
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: false >>> true
D  isItemInDropTarget changed: true >>> false
```

I also should mention, that problem occurs when there is no significant space between targets. So for dragging under last target and returning to it or dragging up between two target with more space between, it will be colored right, but the one up next to it won't.

Comment: `LaunchedEffect` is being called twice for hovered and previously hovered items, and when you drag up, previously hovered value overrides actual one. If you call `LaunchedEffect` only when `isCurrentDropTarget`, you'll fix it but no-item detection will be broken. I would've moved this logic on upper level - you can have onHovered/onUnhovored action for each row, onHovered will set currently hovered item, and if onUnhovored is called for currently hovered item, you're in no item zone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Phil Dukhov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3585796/phil-dukhov) for a comment. I did not get it at first, but after reviewing my code with a colleague we came up with a solution. It is not perfect, but it works.

So, because of triggering Rect.contains() on leaving and entering of two targets we added a map of active targets with their id and correct state. Item is added on hovering and removed on leaving. Final state is got when the map has one item, so it should be either `Enabled` or `Disabled` or it defaults to `Initiated`.

```
private val draggableItemState: DraggableItemState
    get() {
        return if (activeTargetItems.size == 1) {
            activeTargetItems[activeTargetItems.keys.first()]!!
        } else {
            DraggableItemState.Initiated
        }
    }

private var activeTargetItems by mutableStateOf(emptyMap<String, DraggableItemState>())

fun onHoveredTarget(id: String, enabled: Boolean) {
    val draggableItemState = if (enabled) DraggableItemState.Enabled else DraggableItemState.Disabled
    activeTargetItems += (id to draggableItemState)
}

fun onUnHoveredTarget(id: String) {
    activeTargetItems = activeTargetItems.toMutableMap().also { it.remove(id) }
}
```